# Error installing any libraries in paycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

*After calling the "`pip install`" command of any library, an error occurs:*

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2:
   command: 'c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install -
-ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2tu6fau4\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :no
ne: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (24 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
    Using cached setuptools-67.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel
  ERROR: Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 216, in _main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
      return func(self, options, args)
    File "c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 412, in run
      installed = install_given_reqs(
    File "c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 82, in install_given_reqs
      requirement.install(
    File "c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 778, in install
      scheme = get_scheme(
    File "c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 185, in get_scheme
      scheme = distutils_scheme(
    File "c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 118, in distutils_scheme
      assert not (home and prefix), "home={} prefix={}".format(home, prefix)
  AssertionError: home=C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-target-tdo35poo prefix=C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2tu6fau4\overlay
  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 2: 'c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\roman\appdata\local\programs\python\python
38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\roman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2tu6fau4\overlay' --no-warn-script-location -
-no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.`
```

**Important nuances:**

1. I have a new project in paycharm without modules.
2. Pure Python 3.9
3. pip (python 3.8).
4. I am not an admin in Windows 10 system.
5. I correctly added Python 3.9 to the system path.
6. Installing libraries through the interpreter settings also gives the same error
7. I reinstalled python and paycharm
8. I tried writing `pip3` and `--no-user`

Comment: What do you mean with "Pure Python 3.9" and "pip (python 3.8)"? You need to use the pip that's shipped with your Python interpreter.

Comment: `pip3` is a Posix command, and (unless set otherwise) will not be valid in Win10. Also `--no-user` is not a valid switch on my version of `pip` (3.11), I think you may be confused with `--user` which forces an install without root access/admin privileges. This sounds like what you want (also I wish to echo @AKX 's comment that you should be using the version of `pip` that came with your Python version, and morover, should probably only have one install of Python system-wide (research `virtual envrinoments` if you need to have multiple versions)

Comment: there's the free Pycharm version (Community) and then there's the paycharm version with some added features and not free. Which version do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon googling the error `assert not (home and prefix)`, we can find [this pypa/pip issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8438) where [someone has solved this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8438#issuecomment-1210848898) by making sure their `pip.conf` doesn't have a `target` line.

You should make sure your pip configuration files don't have extraneous cruft left over in them and/or that nothing has set a `PIP_TARGET` environment variable or similar.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! This is exactly what was needed.. When I was a beginner, I accidentally registered the installation location for the first project in the pip [global] configuration file.. I couldn't install libraries properly for about 2 months and used replit ahahah.. bruh (=

Comment: There is generally never a need to touch pip.conf. Glad I could help!